# Invoke specific ANT target in Jenkins if it exists

Tags: regex, jenkins, ant

I would like to conditionally invoke a specific ANT target in Jenkins if that target exists in a given ANT build.xml file. I've tried using a Conditional Step, using a regex match on the contents of the build.xml file.

[image]

So I'm trying to detect the presence of the ANT target **publish-all** with the ANT script file build.xml, and it it exists, invoke it.

I'm using the Expression: **^.*publish-all.*$**

With the Label:  **${FILE,path="build.xml"}**

However I get the following error:

```
2019.06.28 15:49:19 Exception caught evaluating condition: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.MacroEvaluationException: Unrecognized macro 'basedir' in '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
2019.06.28 15:49:19 <project name="My Project" basedir="." default="publish-local">
2019.06.28 15:49:19     
2019.06.28 15:49:19     <property file="${basedir}/build.properties"/>
```

Followed by the rest of the contents of the build.xml file which contains the publish-all target.

It seems to be trying to actually parse the build.xml file for tokens and is tripping up on the ANT property **${basedir}**, rather than just treating it like plain text to perform the regex pattern match against, as I expected.
Is there a way to get this to work, or another method altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up trying to use: **Regular expression match** and just switched to an **Execute Shell** instead. There I used a simple grep command to check if the string: **name="publish-all"** was present in the ANT build.xml file.

```
#!/bin/bash
grep name=\"publish-all\" build.xml
```

The Run Condition evaluates to true if the exit value of the shell was zero (which grep returns on a match). Grep return a non-zero value when it does not match.

Here is what it looked like in my Jenkins Job Configuration:

[image]